# not expected bubble sort issue in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a problem with this code, bubble sort is not working properly.

```
numero = raw_input('Ingrese los numeros a ordenar:')
numeros = []

while numero != '': #hit enter to finish the number input
    numeros.append(numero)
    numero = raw_input()

def burbuja(temporal):
    tamanio = len(temporal) -1
    ordenado = False
    while not ordenado:
        ordenado = True
        for i in range(tamanio):
            if temporal[i] > temporal[i+1]:
                ordenado = False
                temporal[i], temporal[i+1] = temporal[i+1], temporal[i]

burbuja(numeros)
print 'Los numeros ordenados son:', numeros
```

The problem is when I insert numbers like this

```
'22', '13, '2', '4'
```

My expected result is

```
'2', '4', '13', '22'
```

But I get:

```
'13', '2' ,'22', '4'
```

I hope you can help me to resolve my problem

Thank you :)

Comment: You have a lexical sort rather than a numeric sort. Convert from string to int before sorting.

Answer (score 0):

you just compare number with its next number. In your example, you just compare "22" with its next number('13') instead of all of other numbers('13','2','4'). So you just exchange '22' with '13'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
def bubble(L):
    length = len(L)
    while length > 0:
        for i in range(length - 1):
            if L[i] > L[i+1]:
                L[i], L[i+1] = L[i+1], L[i]
        length -= 1
    return L
```